# Flask pagination arg resets on redirect

Tags: python, flask

So I am trying to setup an index page with the first 20 'events' from my database, with the option of going further or backwards.
Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    page = int(request.args.get('page', default=1, type=int))
    print("page is " + str(page))
    page_backwards = str((page - 1))
    print("page_backwards is " + page_backwards)
    page_forwards = str((page + 1))
    print("page_fowards is " + page_forwards)


    if request.method == 'GET':

        offset = int(20 * (page - 1))
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        if page <= 0:
            return redirect('/?page=1')

        if page == 1:
            events = cursor.execute(
                "SELECT name, date, time, venue, id FROM events ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 20").fetchall()
            
        elif page > 1:
            events = cursor.execute(
                "SELECT name, date, time, venue, id FROM events ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET ?", (offset,)).fetchall()
        return render_template("index.html", events=events)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'previous' in request.form:
            print("POST" + page_backwards)
            return redirect('/?page=' + page_backwards)
        elif 'next' in request.form:
            print("POST "+ page_forwards)
            return redirect('/?page=' + page_forwards)
```

It would be more concise, but I am trying to debug it which is why the page_backwards etc are at the top.

**What is the baffling part?**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'previous' in request.form:
            print("POST" + page_backwards)
            return redirect('/?page=' + page_backwards)
        elif 'next' in request.form:
            print("POST "+ page_forwards)
            return redirect('/?page=' + page_forwards)
```

The Print part here works perfectly, it prints ou the correct page but for some reason the return redirect misbehaves and is locked on to 1 and 2.

What is happening: Upon clicking the PREVIOUS/NEXT button, it subs-tracts/adds 1 to the page variable and then adds that variable as a argument. The variable is updated correctly but WHATEVER happens, the return always redirects to either Page 0 (which then goes to 1) or Page 2!!

This is extremely baffling:

```
page is 5
page_backwards is 4
page_fowards is 6
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2021 16:29:49] "GET /?page=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[...]
page is 1
page_backwards is 0
page_fowards is 2
POST 2
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2021 16:29:52] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
page is 2
page_backwards is 1
page_fowards is 3
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2021 16:29:52] "GET /?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: From what I've understood the POST request seems to be resetting the page variable and therefore defaulting to 1. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, a POST request is something completely separate which won't remember the URL arguments, therefore resetting them to their default. I have done a cleaner workaround in the end:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():

    page = int(request.args.get('page', default=1, type=int))

    offset = int(20 * (page - 1))
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if page <= 0:
        return redirect('/?page=1')

    if page == 1:
        events = cursor.execute(
            "SELECT name, date, time, venue, id FROM events ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 20").fetchall()
            
    elif page > 1:
        events = cursor.execute(
            "SELECT name, date, time, venue, id FROM events ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET ?", (offset,)).fetchall()
    return render_template("index.html", events=events, previous=str(page-1), next=str(page+1))
```

With the following HTML code:

```
  <form action="/" method="GET">
    <button name="page" value = "{{ previous }}"
      class="inline-flex items-center py-2 px-4 mr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700">
      ← Previous
    </button>
    <button name="page" value="{{ next }}"
      class="inline-flex items-center py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700">
      Next →

    </button>
```